# Wiring a timed outside light using a socket

Tags: wiring

I wish to install an outside light. I want to be able to use a plug in timer so i can adjust easily.
The nearest wiring is the lighting circuit. Can i add a socket to this ?

Comment: Yes you can add a receptacle to a lighting circuit, but to tell you *how* we would need more information. "The nearest wiring is the lighting circuit" does not explain how you intend to access the circuit or install the receptacle.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it: Your comment applies If you are certain the OP is in the USA and not, for example, in the UK - where fitting a 13A socket to a 6A circuit would be illegal as well as unecessary. You'd have to add an FCU and an RCD probably and maybe upgrade the wiring to 1.5mm.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick -- what, you couldn't fit a 6A socket to the circuit instead?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel. In the UK, 99.999%† of sockets are BS1363 13A sockets. Some older homes have [BS546](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets:_British_and_related_types#BS_546) sockets and these are still legal and obtainable so you could fit a new but obsolete BS546 2A socket which is shuttered and originally designed for use on a 5A radial circuit. 6A sockets don't exist, there was a BS546 5A socket but that was designed for a *dedicated* 5A radial circuit. († approx :-)).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) no-one makes plug-in timers for BS546 sockets. This approach is much more horrible than fitting a hard-wired timer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that because [hard-wired timers](https://www.google.com/search?q=hardwired+timer) exist.

[image]
[image]

The above are designed for easy fitting to an existing light switch. A five minute job at worst.

To add a new light switch you'd typically extend the circuit as shown at

- [This random website](http://www.lets-do-diy.com/Projects-and-advice/Electrical/Extending-a-lighting-circuit.aspx) (uses new-colours for T&E but you will likely find old colour T&E in older homes and so will end up with a mix but that's OK)

---

Whether you can wire an outside light permanently to a plug that is plugged into a socket/outlet depends on where you live. Plugs are designed for flexible appliance leads and not for solid-core cable used for fixed wiring. In many places it is not permissible to use flexible wires for fixed wiring applications.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it can be done.   You do your hardwiring in the building NOT from the service panel to the lights, but from an **inlet** to the lights.  The inlet is located right next to the receptacle you want to plug your timer into.

[image]

Now you take an extension cord, plug the socket into the inlet and the plug into the receptacle.  Voila, lights power up.

Now you plug your timer into the receptacle.  Then you plug your extension cord's plug into the timer with its socket in the inlet.  *Voila*.

No ground pin on the timer? Get a better one.